# From milli timestamp to epoc time in bash

Tags: linux, date, epoch

I need to convert milli sec timestamp to epoc timestamp

this is a date till millisec : `20230621171905443`

I tried below :

`date -d "${D:0:8} ${D:8:2}:${D:10:2}:${D:12:2}:${D:14:3}" +'%s.%3N'`

date: invalid date ‘20230621 17:19:05:443’

but not getting epoc time

please help.

Comment: It's `HH:MM:SS.millis` not `HH:MM:SS:milis`

Answer (score 0):

D="20230621171905443"

date -d "${D:0:8} ${D:8:2}:${D:10:2}:${D:12:2}.${D:14:3}" +'%s%3N'

1687348145443